# Without reflection is it possible to determine the class to run

Tags: java, database, oop, solid-principles

So i'm in a situation, where i would like to have a database of objects that contain classes to run. It would look something like:

```
id  | Description       | pricingClass
1   | "static pricing"  | staticDeliveryPrice.class
2   | "Dynamic pricing" | dynamicDeliveryPrice.class
```

The purpose of this is to allow flexibility in my coding. My line of thought is, this would allow for multiple ways of determining how to figure out a price of a deliveryMethod.

The problem I'm worried about is, is reflection bad to use in this scenario? Is there a better way to do it? Is it following the solid principles.(I would say yes, but part of me disagree).

Comment: why not create a base DeliveryPrice class and have DynamicDeliveryPrice and StaticDeliveryPrice classes extend it to implement their own delivery method. then all you have to have is a data structure that contains DeliveryPrice objects that you call the same method on. why all the work to map the object types to a string/class?

Comment: Reflection is not bad. Use it if you need it.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I do plan for all my deliveryClass to use an interface to predefine the methods. But would i still need my price object to determine what deliveryPrice it uses?

Answer (score 7):

You're describing a plugin-based architecture. Do you *really* need this kind of flexibility ? It's usually necessary when:

- people **outside** your project need to add new features to your code without your intervention
- you want to allow **runtime** modification of your program.

Otherwise, it's completely overkill. You have full control on what goes in your product, so you can simply rely on good old polymorphism to isolate the different implementations of your feature.

Also, it's not a very good thing to put business logic in the database: you mix concerns, you create strong coupling (suddenly renaming classes will become annoying!), and of course, it's harder to reason about what happens in your code by just looking at it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad you wrote why it was necessary, because it does kind of validate what i'm trying to do. In my user scenario, I would want to be able to at run time change the delivery method, and also allow it for other "clients" to specify the exact costings and how the program interacts with the product.